# Android Studio: No JVM installation found, define JAVA_HOME even after doing so

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am installing the Android Studio for the first time. I am getting this error when I try to open the Studio:

```
No JVM installation found. Please install a 64-bit JDK. If you already have a JDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable
```

I have already installed the most recent Java JDK and have set the JAVA_HOME variable to point to it. For some reason it is still saying it can't find a JVM installation. Any idea how I can solve this? Thanks.

[image]
[image]

java -version:

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

Comment: 2 things. Is it a 64 bit edition? Secondly, reboot your PC.

Comment: Yes, its 64 and I did reboot

Comment: Are you sure? Because its installed in x86.

Comment: I'm 100% sure, just downloaded the newest version...

Comment: Maybe you installed 32bit earlier. Make sure, else it wouldn't be installed in x86.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've installed the 32bit edition of Java ad the files are located in `Program File x86`. Try reinstalling Java and making sure its the 64bit edition. If it was, it would simply be installed in `Program Files`.

Comment: I will uninstall and re-install again. This definitely makes sense but I'm pretty sure I did install 64-bit. Maybe I'm just going crazy.

Comment: Maybe you did install the 64bit. Check Program Files if it has the installation.

Comment: After uninstalling and reinstalling it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i have the same problem i solve that by installing 64bit version of jdk instead of 32 bit and define JAVA_HOME variable in system setting section

Answer (score 0):

Try to export `JAVA_HOME` in `path`, append:

My JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25   (no backslash at the end)

My      path: ...;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;

Comment: post output of `java -version`